# Density of sum of two random variables

Tags: probability, self-learning, density-function

Let$(X,Y)$ be an RV of the continous type  with PDF $f(x,y)$.Let
$Z=X+Y$,then the [Convolution of probability distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_of_probability_distributions) told us the PDF of $Z$ is $f_{Z}(z)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x,z-x)dx$.

If we suppose that

$$f(x,y)= \left\{\begin{matrix}
 p(x,y)&   (y\ge0)  \wedge (x\le y)\\
 0&  \text{otherwise}\\
\end{matrix}\right.$$

From above formula for the distribution of the sum $Z=X+Y$,

I get the PDF of $Z$ as follows:
$$f_{Z}(z)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
 \int_{-\infty}^{z}p(x,z-x)dx &z\le0\\
 \int_{-\infty}^{z/2}p(x,z-x)dx &z> 0 \\
\end{matrix}\right.$$
I'm not sure if this result is correct, please correct me if necessary.